Transistorsoft | BackgroundGeolocation
I have some doubts and some issue with Transistorsoft, for now on Android.
I'm using Transistorsoft on react-native and I don't understand how to ask again for permissions if I deny them the fist time the app asked me.
Because if I try to call "BackgroundGeolocation.start()" nothing happens and also if I recal "BackgroundGeolocation.findOrCreateTransistorAuthorizationToken" and "BackgroundGeolocation.ready" nothing happens too.
On iOS when I call "BackgroundGeolocation.start()" the app ask me again to go to settings and that's fine.
Another question is: since I don't need to send the location on my server in realtime, do I need to set all these steps:
    /// Get an authorization token from demo server at tracker.transistorsoft.com
    const token = await BackgroundGeolocation.findOrCreateTransistorAuthorizationToken(org, username, ENV.TRACKER_HOST);

    /// Configure the plugin.
    const state = await BackgroundGeolocation.ready({
        debug: false,
        logLevel: BackgroundGeolocation.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE,
        transistorAuthorizationToken: token,
        distanceFilter: 10,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
    });

Thanks!
